# Dexie is saying there is a call before Initialization Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, dexie

I created a Dexie Class for the Database like in the TypeScript Example Code. But somehow when I startup my Application I got an Error about that Something on Courses Entity Class is Called before I Init the Class but I don't think this happens in my Code but not sure. Found nothing about this in the Docs so I got stuck.

Dexie Extension Class:

```
class LocalAppStorage extends Dexie {
  // Declare implicit table properties.
  // (just to inform Typescript. Instanciated by Dexie in stores() method)
  courses: Dexie.Table<Course, number>; // number = type of the primkey
  //...other tables goes here...

  constructor() {
    super("YoutubeFitnessDatabase");
    this.version(1).stores({
      courses:
        "++id, title, url, thumbnail_url",
      //...other tables goes here...
    });
    // The following line is needed if your typescript
    // is compiled using babel instead of tsc:
    this.courses = this.table(
      "courses",
    );
    this.courses.mapToClass(Course);
  }
}

export const db = new LocalAppStorage();
```

And I created an custom Class For Entity Table:

```
export default class Course {
  constructor(
    //@ts-ignore
    public title: string,
    //@ts-ignore
    public url: string,
    //@ts-ignore
    public thumbnail_url: string,
    //@ts-ignore
    public id?: number,
  ) {}

  async save() {
    await db.transaction(
      "rw",
      db.courses,
      async () => {
        this.id = await db.courses.put(
          this,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This is the full Error I got:

```
error - ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Course' before initialization
    at Module.eval [as default] (webpack-internal:///./src/entities/course.entitiy.ts:2:99)
    at new LocalAppStorage (webpack-internal:///./src/store/LocalAppStorage.ts:28:82)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/store/LocalAppStorage.ts:33:12)
    at Module../src/store/LocalAppStorage.ts (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:602:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:29:31)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/entities/course.entitiy.ts:3:83)
    at Module../src/entities/course.entitiy.ts (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:530:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:29:31)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/CreateCourseMenu.tsx:12:85)
    at Module../src/components/CreateCourseMenu.tsx (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:423:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:29:31)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:13:86)
    at Module../src/pages/_app.tsx (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:578:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:29:31)
    at Object.0 (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:649:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/jannik/Desktop/youtube-fitness/.next/server/pages/_app.js:29:31)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the typical circular reference problem: Course.ts imports LocalAppStorage.ts which imports Course.ts. This is totally ok unless if it was for the fact that the instance of LocalAppStorage is executed inline in LocalAppStorage.ts.

Solution: Break out const db to a new module db.ts where you instanciate it.

```
// db.ts
import { LocalAppStorage } from "./LocalAppStorage";

export const db = new LocalAppStorage();
```

Comment: Makes sense I will try that out, thanks for your help

Comment: Tried it out but still got the.same Error. I think I will try to reproduce the Error in an Codepen

Comment: I tried to make [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/dexiejs-entity-issue-example-g21wf) but the persitence somehow not works, at least you can see how I tried to persist my Entity

Comment: To add something I use the latest alpha for compability with react-hooks for dexie, maybe that is the actual Issue?

Comment: I see. The problem is still circular imports as Course imports instance which imports LocalAppStorage which imports Course. I tried another solution in this fork of your codesandbox where db is a static getter of Store instead of a global const. I also added the use of useLiveQuery() to display a list of Courses. https://codesandbox.io/s/dexiejs-entity-issue-example-forked-mjkcg?file=/store/store.ts